# Where should I unpack a Tor browser?

Tags: software-installation, tor

I've download an archive with a Tor browser from their official website. Where should I unpack it? Should it necessarily be a user's directory and any high level directory will do also? Say, `/opt`.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack it anywhere. I usually unpack such applications in the `Apps` directory inside my home directory.